# Quiz show probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

These questions are from a chapter on combinatorics in a math book. I can only answer a). I only have a few thoughts on b) and c).

Lena has enrolled herself in a quiz program on TV. She has studied the questions thoroughly and found the probabilities of whether she is going to answer the questions correctly. The first round has five questions, and Lena must answer correctly on all of them to get to the next round. The questions in this round are quite easy, and Lena believes that the probability to answer a question correctly is p=0.95.

a) What is the probability that Lena will answer all five questions correctly.
My answer: $0.95^5=0.77$

b) In the second round Lena will get 10 questions and must answer a minimum of 8 of the correctly. The questions in this round are harder, and Lena figures that the probability of a correct answer is now q=0.75. Explain why there are 45 different ways of picking 2 of the 10 questions. Use this to show that Lena has a probability of around 0.28 to answer correctly on exactly 8 of the questions in this round.

My thoughts: The reason there are 45 ways of picking 2 of the ten questions is $\binom{10}{2}=45$
The probability of an incorrect answer is 0.25

c) Find the probability that Lena will make it through both first and second round.

My thoughts: Probability of making round 1 multiplied by probability of making round 2.

Comment: You don't understand anything about b & c? You don't understand why there are $45$ different ways to pick two of the ten questions?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have written that i understand $\binom{10}{2}=45$

Comment: Good. Now, if the probsbility of a correct answer is $0.75$, what's the probability of an incorrect answer?

Comment: @GerryMyerson The probability of an incorrect answer is 0.25

Comment: Good! You know much more than you let on. Now, assuming the questions are independent of each other, what's the probability that you get, say, questions 1 and 2 wrong, and the other eight questions right?

Comment: @GerryMyerson $0.25^2 * 0.75^8$

Comment: Terrific! What was so hard about that? And you already have the right idea for part c. Write it all up! Post it as an answer!

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have posted an answer now.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: To be fair, it's not always clear to students what exactly they know and what they don't know! :-)

Comment: @Brian everybody knows everything! They just don't know that they know everything.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Pretty sure I don't know everything! :-)

Comment: @Gerry Myerson I wish I had a guide like you. You deserve respect.

Comment: @The any teacher can do what I did, and most of them are happy to try. Students should take more advantage of that.

Comment: Well, my professors aren't like that. They try their best to avoid students asking questions.

Comment: @The report them to their department heads. That's not how teachers are meant to behave.

Answer (score 2):

b) The probability of an incorrect answer is 0.25. The probability of for instance getting questions 1 and 2 wrong, and the other eight questions right is $0.25^2*0.75^8=0.006257$.

The probability of all all the possible selections are $45*0.006257=0.28$

c) We also have to calculate the probability of getting 9 and 10 questions right. The probability of for instance getting question 1 wrong, and the other nine questions right is $0.25*0.75^9=0.01878$. Times 10 ($\binom{10}{1}$) is $0.01878*10=0.19$

The probability of getting 10 questions right is $0.75^{10}=0.05631$ There is only one possible selection. The probability of making it through round 2 is $0.28 + 0.19+0.056=0.526$

The probability of making it through first and second round is $0.77*0.526=0.40$

Comment: Good! But in a few places, you have $a*b$ where you mean to have $a^b$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Fixed it